# Inserting variables within {} in Python3 when printing

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to have a variable within the curly braces in Python3 to change the formatting of my output like so:

```
numSpaces = 10
f.write("{:<numSpaces}".format(i))
```

How do I do this and how would I be able to specify whether `i` is an integer, string, float, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax):

> A `format_spec` field can also include nested replacement fields within it. These nested replacement fields may contain a field name, conversion flag and format specification, but deeper nesting is not allowed. The replacement fields within the `format_spec` are substituted before the `format_spec` string is interpreted. This allows the formatting of a value to be dynamically specified.

---

So, for example, you could use:

```
In [207]: "{i:<{numspaces}}".format(numspaces=10, i=123)
Out[207]: '123       '
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always do

```
("{:"+str(numSpaces)+"}").format(i)
```

Alternatively,

```
("{:{numSpaces}}").format(i, numSpaces=4)
```